# PHCachingImageManager not caching Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, image, caching, swift3, photokit

I am working with the Photos framework in iOS to develop an overlay for my app which works similar to a WhatsApp overlay. In order to get access to the user's gallery image assets, I need to use Photos and cannot get away with using UIImagePickerController.

In order to get introduced better with the framework, I decided to first build my own image picker and I started off with loading images from my gallery and putting it into a collection view on a simple screen. Once I got the assets using `PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) as PHFetchResult<PHAsset>`

Then, I use these assets in an array and start caching in the default PHCachingManager as follows:

```
cachingImageManager.startCachingImages(for: self.assets,
                                               targetSize: CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0),
                                               contentMode: .default,
                                               options: nil)
```

In my cellForItemAtIndexPath for the collectionView, I use:

```
cachingImageManager.requestImage(for: assets[indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0), contentMode: .default, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
        cell.imageView.image = image
    })
```

As you can see, as per the Apple documentation, I use caching with exactly the same targetSize, contentMode and options in both places and as such, the callback block where I set the image should be called exactly once with the high quality image.

However, if I reload the collectionView, or even on the first load of the collection view, the call back is called twice, once with a low quality image and the second time with a high quality image.

I can't help but think this is a bug as I downloaded [Apple's tutorial code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/Shared_AssetGridViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Shared_AssetGridViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_6)  for Photos framework and it does the exact thing even though the doc specifically says that if we send the same options, contentMode and targetSize for an asset, it gets called only once as it gets cached. (Even the tutorial code first loads a low quality image followed by a high quality one no matter how many times you reload the collection).

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I am new to AVFoundation coding and have been stumped by this issue.

I'm sorry if this was a really long read, but thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try Kingfisher framework for image catching easy to use and get pod as per  your swift version.

Comment: I need to use only gallery images though, I don't need to download anything

Answer (score -1):

Read about `PHImageRequestOptions` and property `deliveryMode` probably the default value is set to `opportunistic`

> case opportunistic
>
> Photos automatically provides one or more results in order to balance image quality and responsiveness.